# How to get Qt creator running on a fresh system?

Tags: debian, qt

I'm trying to install the Qt development environment on a fresh Debian, without success.
First, the automatic online installer didn't even manage to get me to a usable state, as the xserver was crashing. I had to manually add `buster-backports` to my sources.list (this might get relevant later)

The first thing after, was to download and start the netinstaller from the Qt website. (qt-unified-linux-x64-4.0.1-1-online.run)

The Qt Designer, Translator, and other applications start normally, but qtcreator doesn't.

When starting it from the console, I get the following error:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted
```

With the verbose options (export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1) I get

```
Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/platforms" ...
Cannot load library /opt/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-util.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/opt/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /opt/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-util.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
```

Searching for this error, everyone recommended installing `libxcb-xinerama0`, and almost everyone replied with thanks as it worked.
So I installed it.
And nothing changed.

Another recommendation was "sudo cp ~/.Xauthority /root"

It didn't change anything either.

If I install Qt creator from the "software center" GUI, I get an old version of qtcreator, which runs, but doesn't recognize any of my installed components, so it's just a text editor.

Checking the qt version with `qtdiag` I get

```
Qt 5.11.3 (x86_64-little_endian-lp64 shared (dynamic) release build; by GCC 8.3.0) on "xcb" 
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) [linux version 5.10.0-0.bpo.3-amd64]
```

Which is strange, as I installed Qt 5.15.
Also, I've seen reports of many GUI stuff requiring at least Qt 5.12, so having 5.11 might be a problem. I guess I have Qt 5.11.3 (even before installing Qt) because I run KDE, and KDE uses Qt.

So what now? Just uninstalling Qt via removing any and all packages starting with "qt" will almost surely break my system.

Answer (score 0):

One of the many [forums](https://forum.qt.io/topic/121104/qtcreator-fails-to-start-after-last-update/4) of qt did provide an answer:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-util.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-util.so.1
```

Qt creator now starts.
I still couldn't build any GUI programs, not even a "hello world" one, until installing `libgl1-mesa-dev` (how should I have guessed its name? The error was a generic "can't find IGL")